# Issue scalling width of svg elements while updating D3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I created a simple age pyramid bar chart with D3.js using this example as a guide: http://www.jasondavies.com/d3-pyramid/. This works fine but I want to dynamically update this chart based on a users selection of data. When I append the new data to the existing bars the < g > element and rects grow beyond the width of the svg container. My first thought was to set a max width of the < g > elements to the width of the container hoping that the rects would scale accordingly like they did in the initial rendering but that does not seem to be possible.

My biggest issue ( besides needing to clean up the code :) ) is that I don't understand why the bar widths look great in the initial rendering but then grow exceedingly in the update. I think this is probably some fundamental misunderstanding i have with D3/SVG but I could use some guidance.

Any help is appreciated!

### Initial Chart Generation (this works)

```
var ageChart,
ageBar,
ageBars,
ageTotal,
dataRange,
yScale,
topMargin,
ageChartWidth,
ageLabelSpace,
ageInnerMargin,
commas = d3.format(",.0f");

function generateAgeChart(data) {

ageData = processAgeData(data);

ageLabelSpace = 25;
ageInnerMargin = width / 2 + ageLabelSpace;

var outerMargin = 30,
gap = 8,   
leftLabel = "Female",
rightLabel = "Male",
height = 180;
barWidth = height / ageData.length;


width = 200;
ageChartWidth = width - ageInnerMargin - outerMargin;
topMargin = 25;
yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, ageData.length]).range([0, height - topMargin]);
dataRange = d3.max(ageData.map(function (d) { return Math.max(d.female, d.male) }));
ageTotal = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, dataRange]).range([0, ageChartWidth - ageLabelSpace]);


/* main panel */
ageChart = d3.select("#chart-3").append("svg")
    .attr("class", "d3-chart")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

/* female label */
ageChart.append("text")
  .attr("class", "bar-label")
  .text(leftLabel)
  .attr("x", width - ageInnerMargin)
  .attr("y", topMargin - 3)
  .attr("text-anchor", "end");

/* male label */
ageChart.append("text")
  .attr("class", "bar-label")
  .text(rightLabel)
  .attr("x", ageInnerMargin)
  .attr("y", topMargin - 3);

/* bars and data labels */
ageBar = ageChart.selectAll("g.bar")
    .data(ageData)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
        return "translate(0," + (yScale(i) + topMargin) + ")";
    });

var highlight = function (c) {
    return function (d, i) {
        ageBar.filter(function (d, j) {
            return i === j;
        }).attr("class", c);
    };
};

ageBar
  .on("mouseover", highlight("highlight bar"))
  .on("mouseout", highlight("bar"));

ageBar.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "femalebar")
    .attr("height", barWidth - gap);

ageBar.append("text")
    .attr("class", "femalebar")
    .attr("dx", -3)
    .attr("dy", "1.7em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end");

ageBar.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "malebar")
    .attr("height", barWidth - gap)
    .attr("x", ageInnerMargin);

ageBar.append("text")
    .attr("class", "malebar")
    .attr("dx", 3)
    .attr("dy", "1.7em");

/* sharedLabels */
ageBar.append("text")
    .attr("class", "shared")
    .attr("x", width / 2)
    .attr("dy", "1.7em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function (d) { return d.sharedLabel; });

// Draw the chart
ageBars = d3.selectAll("g.bar")
    .data(ageData);

ageBars.selectAll("rect.malebar")
    .transition()
    .attr("width", function (d) { return ageTotal(d.male); });

ageBars.selectAll("rect.femalebar")
    .transition()
    .attr("x", function (d) { return ageInnerMargin - ageTotal(d.female) - 2 * ageLabelSpace; })
    .attr("width", function (d) { return ageTotal(d.female); });

ageBars.selectAll("text.malebar")
    .text(function (d) { return commas(d.male); })
    .transition().attr("x", function (d) { return ageInnerMargin + ageTotal(d.male); });

ageBars.selectAll("text.femalebar")
    .text(function (d) { return commas(d.female); })
    .transition()
    .attr("x", function (d) { return ageInnerMargin - ageTotal(d.female) - 2 * ageLabelSpace; });

// Title
ageChart.append("text")
    .attr("x", (width / 2))
    .attr("y", 10)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("font-size", "10pt")
    .style("fill", "#333960")
    .style("font-weight", "bold")
    //.style("text-decoration", "underline")
    .style("font-weight", "bold")
    .text("Age");
 }
```

### Re-Draw Chart Function (the problem area)

```
function redrawAgeChart(data) {

// Get and process data
ageData = processAgeData(data);


width = 200;
height = 180;
outerMargin = 30;
topMargin = 25;
gap = 8;
height = 180;
barWidth = height / ageData.length;
ageLabelSpace = 25;
ageInnerMargin = width / 2 + ageLabelSpace;

ageChartWidth = width - ageInnerMargin - outerMargin;


yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, ageData.length]).range([0, height - topMargin]);
dataRange = d3.max(ageData.map(function (d) { return Math.max(d.female, d.male) }));
ageTotal = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, dataRange]).range([0, ageChartWidth - ageLabelSpace]);    


ageBars = d3.selectAll("g.bar")
    .data(ageData);

ageBars.selectAll("rect.malebar")
    .transition()
    .attr("width", function (d) { return ageTotal(d.male); });

ageBars.selectAll("rect.femalebar")
    .transition()
    .attr("x", function (d) { return ageInnerMargin - ageTotal(d.female) - 2 * ageLabelSpace; })
    .attr("width", function (d) { return ageTotal(d.female); });

ageBars.selectAll("text.malebar")
    .text(function (d) { return commas(d.male); })
    .transition().attr("x", function (d) { return ageInnerMargin + ageTotal(d.male); });

ageBars.selectAll("text.femalebar")
    .text(function (d) { return commas(d.female); })
    .transition().attr("x", function (d) { return ageInnerMargin - ageTotal(d.female) - 2 * ageLabelSpace; });

}
```

### Get data function (you can hit this service... it is public)

```
function processAgeData(data) {
ageData = [];

var totalF_6_17 = 0;
var totalF_18_34 = 0;
var totalF_35_54 = 0;
var totalF_55_plus = 0;
var totalF_under5 = 0;

var totalM_6_17 = 0;
var totalM_18_34 = 0;
var totalM_35_54 = 0;
var totalM_55_plus = 0;
var totalM_under5 = 0;

// Loop through return to build a new array of values
$.each(data.features, function (key, val) {

    var f_6_17 = val.properties.f_6_17;
    var f_18_34 = val.properties.f_18_34;
    var f_35_54 = val.properties.f_35_54;
    var f_55_plus = val.properties.f_55_plus;
    var f_under5 = val.properties.f_under5;

    var m_6_17 = val.properties.m_6_17;
    var m_18_34 = val.properties.m_18_34;
    var m_35_54 = val.properties.m_35_54;
    var m_55_plus = val.properties.m_55_plus;
    var m_under5 = val.properties.m_under5;


    totalF_6_17 = totalF_6_17 + f_6_17;
    totalF_18_34 = totalF_18_34 + f_18_34;
    totalF_35_54 = totalF_35_54 + f_35_54;
    totalF_55_plus = totalF_55_plus + f_55_plus;
    totalF_under5 = totalF_under5 + f_under5;

    totalM_6_17 = totalM_6_17 + m_6_17;
    totalM_18_34 = totalM_18_34 + m_18_34;
    totalM_35_54 = totalM_35_54 + m_35_54;
    totalM_55_plus = totalM_55_plus + m_55_plus;
    totalM_under5 = totalM_under5 + m_under5;
});

var under5Obj = new Object();
under5Obj.sharedLabel = "< 5";
under5Obj.female = totalF_under5;
under5Obj.male = totalM_under5;

var age6_17Obj = new Object();
age6_17Obj.sharedLabel = "6 - 17";
age6_17Obj.female = totalF_6_17;
age6_17Obj.male = totalM_6_17;

var age18_34Obj = new Object();
age18_34Obj.sharedLabel = "18 - 34";
age18_34Obj.female = totalF_18_34;
age18_34Obj.male = totalM_18_34;

var age35_54Obj = new Object();
age35_54Obj.sharedLabel = "35 - 54";
age35_54Obj.female = totalF_35_54;
age35_54Obj.male = totalM_35_54;

var over55Obj = new Object();
over55Obj.sharedLabel = "55 +";
over55Obj.female = totalF_55_plus;
over55Obj.male = totalM_55_plus;

ageData.push(under5Obj);
ageData.push(age6_17Obj);
ageData.push(age18_34Obj);
ageData.push(age35_54Obj);
ageData.push(over55Obj);

return ageData;
}

    // Age Chart Request
    //// use this url to get the entire dataset which should display correctly
    url = 'http://gis.drcog.org/geoserver/DRCOGPUB/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=DRCOGPUB:rea_demographics_age_county_view&maxFeatures=10000&outputFormat=json&propertyName=f_under5,f_6_17,f_18_34,f_35_54,f_55_plus,m_under5,m_6_17,m_18_34,m_35_54,m_55_plus,geoid&format_options=callback:redrawAgeChart'

    //// use this for the update request
    selectionUrl = "http://gis.drcog.org/geoserver/DRCOGPUB/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=DRCOGPUB:rea_demographics_age_county_view&maxFeatures=10000&outputFormat=json&propertyName=f_under5,f_6_17,f_18_34,f_35_54,f_55_plus,m_under5,m_6_17,m_18_34,m_35_54,m_55_plus,geoid&format_options=callback:redrawAgeChart&cql_filter=geoid%20IN%20('08059')"


    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: url,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(textStatus); }
    });
```

Comment: [This tutorial](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html) might help. It's for bar charts, but a pyramid chart is fundamentally the same. There's nothing that immediately strikes me about your code, but it's a lot of code...

Comment: Thanks Lars! I think I got a bit closer to identifying the issue since this post.  I believe the main issue is a result of the way I recalculate ageTotal (which is the x scale). Decreasing the range() value from range([0,ageChartWidth - ageLabelSpace]) to range([0,5]) forces the output of the smaller input data value after redraw to fit the width of the chart better but not a good solution. NOTE: ageChartWidth - ageLabelSpace = 20.  I think my biggest confusion is why the .range() function doesn't map the max width of the bar to simply be 20px since it is set in .range(0,20)?

Comment: You may have to set both domain and range properly -- if you pass in a value beyond the max of the domain, a particular scale may simply extrapolate past the max of the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I learned a bit about D3 and SVG and managed to catch my rather silly mistakes.  I was appending the data to the rect elements in the wrong way. I solved this by selecting out male/female bars directly from the chart svg separately and appending the data to each of those selections. This now works as planned.

```
    yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, ageData.length]).range([0, height - topMargin]);
dataRange = d3.max(ageData.map(function (d) { return Math.max(d.female, d.male) }));
ageTotal = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, dataRange]).range([0, ageChartWidth - ageLabelSpace]);   


ageChart.selectAll("rect.malebar")
    .data(ageData)
    .transition()
    .attr("width", function (d) { return ageTotal(d.male); });

ageChart.selectAll("rect.femalebar")
    .data(ageData)
    .transition()
    .attr("x", function (d) { return ageInnerMargin - ageTotal(d.female) - 2 * ageLabelSpace; })
    .attr("width", function (d) { return ageTotal(d.female); });


ageChart.selectAll("text.malebar")
    .data(ageData)
    .text(function (d) { return commas(d.male); });
     });

ageChart.selectAll("text.femalebar")
    .data(ageData)
    .text(function (d) { return commas(d.female); });
```